Cannot resolve symbol 'detectCollisions' on Rigidbody2D
I'm simply trying to disable collisions for a Rigidbody2D:
rb.isKinematic = true;
rb.detectCollisions = false;

as per: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-detectCollisions.html
But I get the error Cannot resolve symbol 'detectCollisions'
What's going on here?

You've linked the documentation for the 3D version, Rigidbody, not the 2D version you say you're using, Rigidbody2D. The 2D version indeed does not have a property called .detectCollisions. Try editing your question to describe what gameplay you're trying to use this to accomplish, and we can suggest appropriate ways to implement that in 2D.

@DMGregory thanks for the clarification, that makes sense now. But I think the question that remains is clear enough - how would I disable collisions for a Rigidbody2D absent a detectCollisions property? The solution I have so far is rb.excludeLayers= LayerMask.GetMask("Cats"); but that just excludes other objects on the Cats layer.

The question is, why do you want to disable collisions? We might approach that in different ways depending on the situation (e.g. whether you just need to prevent bouncing, or need to prevent collision callbacks to one specific script you control, or need to prevent callbacks across many scripts that may be out of your control, etc.). You can always exclude a layerMask that's all 1 bits, but depending on your situation that may or may not be the most efficient route.


The solution I have so far is rb.excludeLayers= LayerMask.GetMask("Cats"); but that just excludes other objects on the Cats layer.

Did you consider rb.excludeLayers = -1;? This gives you a mask of all "1" bits, meaning "exclude everything".
